# Отсутствие перевода при загрузке картинки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, мобильная-версия

При задании вопроса в мобильной версии сайта страницы загрузки картинки не переведены:

[image: Add picture]

[image: Upload]

[image: Cancel]

Также отсутствует перевод текста описания по умолчанию для картинки:

[image: Описание]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, некоторые предложения были неправильно записаны в код и поэтому не появились в Transifex. Я их починил, так что они там скоро появятся.

Извините, пожалуйста. Новый программист у нас ещё не привык к локализации. :)

Comment: Какая душещипательная история. Ничего, скоро привыкнет. Накидаем ему новых локализационных багов. Вы очень хорошо пишите по-русски для канадского американца. Новая версия Google.Translate? :)

Comment: @alexolut Я из Питера. :) Родители в Канаду переехали, когда мне было 15, ну и я с ними.

Comment: то-то я смотрю имя какое-то слишком петербургское :) ну, круто, земляк!