# Есть ли примеры случаев, когда обсуждение на Мете что-то действительно меняло в платформе ruSO?

Tags: обсуждение

На данном сайте (Мета), часто обсуждаются различные предложения о полезных нововведениях, которые могли бы в той или иной степени улучшить работу сайта, его удобство, полезность и т.д. Ряд таких нововведений охотно принимается участниками сообщества без каких-либо возражений, однако, по моему небольшому опыту на сайте, такие предложения так и остаются на стадии обсуждения.

Отсюда вопрос: был ли когда-либо случай, когда предложенное одним участником на Мете и одобренное сообществом нововведение было действительно реализовано на сайте? Или все эти предложения – лишь пустая трата времени?

Вопрос именно о сайте (платформе).

Answer (score 6):

Если нужно что-то глобально менять, то лучше это делать сразу на MSE. К примеру, [вот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345667/260198).

Из предложений, касающихся именно нас, [локализация Q/A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347163/260198). Ну и в целом, большая часть предложений касается обычно локализаций и багов.

Предложения с ruSO обычно дальше сайта не идут и касаются локальных правил.

Answer (score 2):

На нашей Мете основной язык - русский. У тех кто поддерживает "платформу" - скорее всего, какой-то другой. Делайте выводы... Раньше Adam Lear иногда [реагировал на сообщения об ошибках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3903/240512), он понимает русский, но потом это как-то заглохло. Все, что требует внимания разработчиков, следует отправлять на [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), это на порядки увеличит вероятность того, что на вопрос прореагируют.

Comment: Поставил бы плюс, но к сожалению, ответ в текущем виде не является ответом на вопрос *"был ли когда-либо случай, когда предложенное одним участником на Мете и одобренное сообществом нововведение было действительно реализовано на сайте? Или все эти предложения – лишь пустая трата времени?"*

Comment: Но можно сначала обсудить локально, а потом уже приходить на метамету с продуманным решением, а не идеей - полагаю, так будет больше шансов на какую-то реакцию.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно список вопросов, которые являются предложениями некоторой функциональности и при этом были реализованы можно найти с учётом меток [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) + [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Сейчас возвращается [208 вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Возможно, к этому списку стоит добавить ещё и вариант с меткой [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Отдельно это даст ещё
[129 вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

В общем, всё зависит о того, какого рода нововведения вы хотите учитывать в результатах поиска, но в целом можно опираться на те вопросы, которые имеют метку [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), а дальше уже уточнять поиск.

Аналогичные действия по поиску можно проделать и для глобального мета сайта: [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).